# How to assign properties of objects in an array to multiple class properties?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, foreach

I have a typescript class with 2 private properties and an array of objects.

```
class AssigningProperties {
  private animalType1: string;
  private animalType2: string;

  animals = [
    {
      name: "Bob",
      type: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "Max",
      type: "dog"
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.animals.forEach(v => console.log(v.name));
  }
}

new AssigningProperties ();
```

I want to assign the class property `animalType1` to `cat` and `animalType2` to `dog`, preferably using `Array.foreach`.

I can assign it using index of the objects like so:
`this.animalType1 = this.animals[0].type;` but I feel there's a better approach. Help?

[Link to CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-breeze-kcpes?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts&theme=dark)

Comment: *"I want to assign the class property `animalType1` to `cat`..."* Minor terminology nitpick: "class property" usually means `static` property (a property of `AssigningProperties`, the constructor function). `animalType1` is an *instance* property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, but if you want to do it in a loop, make `animalTypes` an array:

```
private animalTypes: string[];
```

Then you'd use the second parameter for the `forEach` callback, which is the index of the entry:

```
this.animals.forEach((v, i) => v.type = this.animalTypes[i]);
```

Or if you meant that you wanted to assign `"cat"` to the first `animalTypes` (which is what your CodeSandbox code is doing), then:

```
this.animals.forEach((v, i) => this.animalTypes[i] = v.type);
```

---

With either of those, you'll end up with the type stored in two places, which creates a maintenance hazard — you can update `animals[0].type` without updating `animalType1`/`animalTypes[0]`.

Assuming you wanted `animals` to be the one source of truth, you might use getters instead:

```
private get animalType1(): string {
 return this.animals[0].type;
}
private get animalType2(): string {
  return this.animals[1].type;
}
```

[Live Copy on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCUEsDmA7BKkAUBOB7ADgKbYAuChMA3gFDTT7YIBuYJh0ShJ0YaAtmBAAVAJ5EAjAAoAlAC5oEEowzQadOti4BXbCmgkAFgggA6XggEgIAbQAMAXRMkxhANy1oAXw8Nmrdpzc5paiRABMMvKKykiqHhrauvpGpsGCNuKOzkTudN4eaVbQALzQ1vFx6uooYHyE8gBEAEK4AEYNADQVdNn10A3ArA0Vnl1ValXQNXWNALJgAB6d3foujQAmuEjDVd509u4ewLgo0VrAJLjYMpVe1B4QBrgA7jcTdMenuCCEJiBbkgABoZjGZ+IJQoRxNBjNAACSUEGpcHCFziTyA6S5O75FCEZ5wRCodBYPBEUjkCAyEyPF4yVxAA)

Or for the `animalTypes` approach, you'd use a Proxy:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  type: string;
}
class AssigningProperties {
  animals: Animal[] = [
    {
      name: "Bob",
      type: "cat"
    },
    {
      name: "Max",
      type: "dog"
    }
  ];
  private animalTypes = new Proxy<Animal[]>(this.animals, {
    get(target, propName) {
      if (propName in target) {
        return Reflect.get(target, propName).type;
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

[Live Copy on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChlkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY5MATwAcrb6nWAX0IIccGjTQTgjDCEYAFKAHseUMMAiSiJOBmw4a1dFlwBtALrIAvMjNsSOks7IVqAIgBCygEbuANA7OnDweCHBg7kGCgc4EQSSuvO4AsnAAHgEJ7NzJACbKjFFxwiQWrCRcDABuESh6pjgAKrk2pBAA7shKyukcADwmBpYAfAAUYAAWwDQAdA0GNP7xcYwQYBNwUGtgy1WqAHLkEACUK3HIwDDIY-tcRxSXIOxbO2dOF8hQ6wCuUM8AJQgMBwEAQYFmO0223WexU92OJ1mIQgFQupQu3zAf2ePxAeWBoAgeTRJAxghOrDYCGUIDoUB+4OUUDG7zYwjYNEmyg6rPOJBpdOUoNmOEKYwABlMZvN9LgWjwzAAGCxWGbIAAk+GlcwW8tyyosggllPZhA5IE6UhoMjkinh0A0WlZsy5PNZzCAA)

Comment: Thank you for a quick and detailed response. Getter were such a simple but effective approach. I'll deep dive into `Proxy` to understand it but thank you for introducing that to me. Super resourceful.

Comment: @ManishShrestha - Glad to help! FWIW, I cover Proxy in my book (see my profile) in Chapter 14. ;-)